# How do i allow user to change text in vbs?

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

How do i make a vbs msgbox that allow the user to change text?
X:msgbox=("i want to change ''this''?" ,0+32, "what if")

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
value = InputBox("Enter something")
```

The `value` variable will be set to whatever the user enters.  For a default value you can use:

```
value = InputBox("Enter something", , "Default value here")
```